# How can I update a specific value on a custom configuration file?

Tags: python, configuration-files

Assuming I have a configuration txt file with this content:

```
{"Mode":"Classic","Encoding":"UTF-8","Colors":3,"Blue":80,"Red":90,"Green":160,"Shortcuts":[],"protocol":"2.1"}
```

How can i change a specific value like `"Red":90` to `"Red":110` in the file without changing its original format?

I have tried with configparser and configobj but as they are designed for .INI files I couldn't figure out how to make it work with this custom config file. I also tried splitting the lines searching for the keywords witch values I wanted to change but couldn't save the file the same way it was before. Any ideas how to solve this? (I'm very new in Python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like json so you could:

```
import json

obj  = json.load(open("/path/to/jsonfile","r"))
obj["Blue"] = 10
json.dump(obj,open("/path/to/mynewfile","w"))
```

but be aware that a json dict does not have an order.
So the order of the elements is not guaranteed (and normally it's not needed) json lists have an order though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

```
import json

d = {} # store your data here

with open('config.txt','r') as f:
   d = json.loads(f.readline())

d['Red']=14
d['Green']=15
d['Blue']=20
result = "{\"Mode\":\"%s\",\"Encoding\":\"%s\",\"Colors\":%s,\
         \"Blue\":%s,\"Red\":%s,\"Green\":%s,\"Shortcuts\":%s,\
         \"protocol\":\"%s\"}"%(d['Mode'],d['Encoding'],d['Colors'],
                                d['Blue'],d['Red'],d['Green'],
                                d['Shortcuts'],d['protocol'])


with open('config.txt','w') as f:
   f.write(result)
   f.close()

print result
```